# SAPUI5 Error resource URL

Tags: resources, sapui5

I'm programing in SAPUI5 for mobile application, and I'm using the SAPUI Tools developer.

I create a default project with XML application view.

I'm receiving the follow error:

```
2015-02-12 15:44:21 Device API logging initialized - DEVICE
sap-ui-core.js:80 2015-02-12 15:44:21 registerResourcePath ('', 'https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/') -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
sap-ui-core.js:80 2015-02-12 15:44:21 registerResourcePath ('com/maxinst', './') -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
sap-ui-core.js:80 2015-02-12 15:44:21 registerResourcePath ('com/maxinst/mobile', 'maxinstmobile/') -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
sap-ui-core.js:80 2015-02-12 15:44:21 URL prefixes set to: -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
sap-ui-core.js:80 2015-02-12 15:44:21   (default) : https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/ -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
sap-ui-core.js:80 2015-02-12 15:44:21   'com/maxinst' : ./ -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
sap-ui-core.js:80 2015-02-12 15:44:21   'com/maxinst/mobile' : maxinstmobile/ -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem
sap-ui-core.js:27 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
sap-ui-core.js:27 XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/jquery-mobile-custom.js".
sap-ui-core.js:27 XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/core/library-preload.json".
sap-ui-core.js:27 XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/library-preload.json".
sap-ui-core.js:27 XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/commons/library-preload.json".
sap-ui-core.js:27 XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/layout/library-preload.json".
sap-ui-core.js:27 XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/core/themes/sap_bluecrystal/library-parameters.json".
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/themes/sap_bluecrystal/library-parameters.json".
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/layout/themes/sap_bluecrystal/library-parameters.json".
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/commons/themes/sap_bluecrystal/library-parameters.json".
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/m/messagebundle_en_US.properties".
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/maxinstMobile/Component-preload.js".
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/maxinstMobile/Component.js".
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/signals.js".
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/hasher.js".
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js XHR finished loading: GET "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/crossroads.js".
UIComponent.js:6 Uncaught Error: resource URL './' has unknown type (should be one of .properties,.hdbtextbundle)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is misleading. It is thrown by the Bundle JavaScript function in `sap-ui-core.js`. That function is used to open a resource bundle file such as `messageBundle_en_US.properties`. That is, the error is not thrown when you register the path in the `index.html` initialization, but later in your code when you attempt to open a resource bundle file. Here is an example from the `init()` function in `Components.js` in the sample project:

```js
const i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel(
    {bundleUrl : [rootPath, mConfig.resourceBundle].join("/")}
);
```

If the `mConfig` variable or the `resourceBundle` property is not defined, then you will see your error message. In this case, you can replace `mConfig.resourceBundle` with a literal string such as `i18n/messageBundle.properties` to test whether that is your issue.

In my case, `mConfig` was not defined. That's a different problem, and I'm off to troubleshoot that now.